# How to restructure Compound interest formula (with regular contributions) to solve for the periodic payment amount

Tags: finance

I need help restructuring this formula to solve for the payment `PMT` rather than the `Total`:

$$ \text{Total} = \text{Compound interest for principal} + \text{Future value of a series} , $$

$$ \text{Total} = P \left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} + \text{PMT} * \frac{\left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt} - 1) }{\frac{r}{n}} . $$

Where:

- $A$ = the future value of the investment/loan, including interest
- $P$ = the principal investment amount (the initial deposit or loan amount)
- $\text{PMT}$ = the monthly payment
- $r$ = the annual interest rate (decimal)
- $n$ = the number of times that interest is compounded per unit t
- $t$ = the time (months, years, etc) the money is invested or borrowed for

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Is PMT the only unknown?  That would be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the total, you can just do a bit of algebraic rearranging:

$$ \text{Total} = P \left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} + \text{PMT} * \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}-1}{\frac{r}{n}} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \text{Total} - P\left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} = \text{PMT} * \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}-1}{\frac{r}{n}} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \frac{r}{n} * \left( \text{Total} - P\left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} \right) = \text{PMT} * \left(\left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}-1\right) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \text{PMT} = \frac{r}{n} * \frac{\text{Total} - P\left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}}{\left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}-1} $$